# Interop Excel HighlightChangesOptions not working

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I'm trying to open an Excel sheet and switch on tracking for changes, then save it.  That way the user can open the Excel file and any edits are tracked.

```
// Create Excel container
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application myExcel = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
// Turn off alerts
myExcel.DisplayAlerts = false; Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbooks myWorkbooks = myExcel.Workbooks;
// Open and Save as shared
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Workbook myWorkbook = myWorkbooks.Open(pathANDfileName);
myWorkbook.SaveAs(Filename: pathANDfileName, AccessMode: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared );
myWorkbook.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAction.xlSaveChanges, pathANDfileName, false);
// Re open as shared and switch on tracking
myWorkbook = myWorkbooks.Open(pathANDfileName);
myWorkbook.HighlightChangesOnScreen = true;
myWorkbook.HighlightChangesOptions(
    When: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlHighlightChangesTime.xlAllChanges,
    Who: (object)"Everyone",
    Where: Type.Missing);
myWorkbook.Close(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlSaveAction.xlSaveChanges, pathANDfileName, false);
// Clean up
myWorkbook = null;
myWorkbooks = null;
myExcel = null;
```

But it's not switching on tracking properly.  "When" is set to "Since I Last Reviewed" instead of "All".  Who is not set at all.

[image]

Above is the results when I open the Excel sheet.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: If you set it to xlNotYetReviewed, does it reflect correctly in Excel?

Comment: @pnuts What exactly is not matching up?  Code if from my project, image is taken from the excel file after I saved it with changes active.

Comment: @dustmouse I set to xlNotYetReviewed but it still showed "Since I last saved".  So it's not setting the when or the who, is it because I'm using type.missing for the where.  Confusing....